# IIS (or .htaccess) URL Rewrite not working correctly - need to capture number argument as query string

Tags: iis, .htaccess, rewrite, url

I'm trying to have:
http://sub.domain.org/123456 become http://sub.domain.org/index.php?q=123456

I have tried many ways, and one way sort of worked, but then all subdirectories (including images) don't work.  I want it to look for numbers only, and then rewrite it.

It's a PHP app running in IIS, so doing the rewrite from either is fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="everything to index">
<match url="^(.*)$" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" />
</rule>
```